# How to test for differences in 3 related measures assessed pre- & post- treatment on the same sample?

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, t-test

I am designing a study to compare whether one specific treatment improves `Quality of life`. I am using a convenience sample ($N=20$). I hope to administer three different questionnaires to each subject pre- and post-intervention (all validated and standardised) to compare pre and post `QOL` measures. One of questionnaires will look at the severity and frequency of presenting symptoms pre and post treatment. I hope to analyse results to show whether symptoms are improved and what impact if any this has on each subjects Quality of life.

Should I use paired t-tests?

Comment: Can you say what each of your questionnaires is supposed to measure? Are they all measuring (essentially) the same construct (ie, QOL), or are they considered unrelated to each other?

Comment: Your statement of "all validated and standardised" raises a concern.  Are they validated and standardised for the population and condition of interest? Validity might not be transferable.  Further, you should be considering whether your sample size has sufficient power to detect a difference.  You should be performing a priori sample size estimates.